# How can I change the values of a log-log plot from exponential notation to numeric values in the lattice package?

Tags: r, lattice

For instance what should I add to this expression:

```
xyplot(a~b, groups=abc, data=super,
       scales=list(x=list(log=TRUE),y=list(log=TRUE)), 
       panel = panel.grid)
```

in order to have 100 instead of 10^2?

Comment: In the scales list have you looked at the labels element from the docs? That sounds like the ticket. `Vector of labels (characters or expressions) to go along with at. Can also be a list like at.` Alternatively, I wonder if you could log transform your data before hand (essentially you're doing that now)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `latticeExtra` package has a number of nifty functions for producing nicer labels for logarithmic axes. In your case, have a look at `xscale.components.log10ticks`.

Here's an example, taken from the [help page](http://latticeextra.r-forge.r-project.org/man/scale.components.html), that shows basically what you want (although here it's the y-axis that gets the labeling you'll want on the x-axis):

```
 xyplot((1:200)/20 ~ (1:200)/20, type = c("p", "g"),
   scales = list(x = list(log = 2), y = list(log = 10)),
   xscale.components = xscale.components.fractions,
   yscale.components = yscale.components.log10ticks)
```

[image]

---

**EDITED, providing an additional example to reply to comments by the original poster**

```
library(latticeExtra)
dat <- 10^seq(-3, 5)
options(scipen=10)
options(digits=10)

xyplot(dat ~ dat, type = c("p", "g"),
   scales = list(x = list(log = 2), y = list(log = 10)),
   xscale.components = xscale.components.log10ticks,
   yscale.components = yscale.components.log10ticks)
```

[image]

Comment: xscale.components = xscale.components.log10ticks turns my x axis 10^8.0 point into 1e+08 instead of the expected 100000000.

Comment: If you first set `options(scipen=10)` (or some large-enough number), and then redo your plot, it will print more digits before deciding to switch to exponential notation. That should fix your problem.

Comment: when using yscale.components = yscale.components.log10ticks the y axis labels disappeared except the smallest label 10...

Comment: @AttilaCsordas -- not sure why that's happening to you. Depending on what it is, I might need to know more about the device you are plotting to, your data, or the other graphical parameters you are setting. In case it'll help, I just added another example plot to my response above. Cheers, and best of luck figuring this out quickly.